# How to make floor in corona from image full width and height 40 pixel s at the bottom of screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to make floor in corona from image ?
I want to stretch image to has contentWidth and 40 height but when I try

```
local horizPost = display.newImage( "images/floor.png", display.contentWidth,  40)
horizPost.x = display.contentWidth / 2
horizPost.y = display.contentHeight - 40
horizPost:scale( 2, 0.5 )
staticMaterial = {density=10, friction=1, bounce=1}
physics.addBody(horizPost, "static", staticMaterial)
```

It shows strange, has body over image in height and in width it has physics hole ( can pass through at both sides).
I want regardless of resolution of phone to create floor which is actually image and that objects cannot pass through (objects has own body and material)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `horizPost:scale( 2, 0.5 )` when scaling an object you are only scaling the image and not the physics applied to it.

The solution below will, regardless of resolution, fit the screen as you requested.

```
local horizPost = display.newImage( "images/floor.png", display.contentWidth,  40)
horizPost.x = display.contentWidth / 2
horizPost.y = display.contentHeight - 40
horizPost.width = display.contentWidth -- Replaced your horizPost:scale(2,0.5)
staticMaterial = {density=10, friction=1, bounce=1}
physics.addBody(horizPost, "static", staticMaterial)
```